# Call function inside href using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this link

```
<a href="alert('Test')" id="myLink"> Test </a>
```

Now when i click directly on the link .. The alert get popped up in my window.

But, `$("#myLink").click();`

doesn't call the popup.

EDIT : I need to trigger the function inside `href` using jQuery

Solved --------- :

```
var x = $('#myLink').attr("href");
window.location = x;
```

Comment: Bind event using `on()`, call the function in event handler, after complete execution of function redirect to the link.

Comment: @Tushar i need to trigger the function inside `href` using jQuery

Comment: What actually you need to do whats your requirements calling an alert can also work like this <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="alert('hello')">test</a>

Comment: @KamranKhatti i know but, i need to call the function inside `href="javascript:alert('test')"` using jQuery

Comment: @atulquest93 than whats wrong with it you can also use any function inside href look into this <a href="javascript:hello()">test</a>
<script>
    function hello(){
        alert('test');
    }
</script>

Comment: html is from different source i have no control over that.. I need to use that as it is. I can only use my js file with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out..

```
var x = $('#myLink').attr("href");
window.location = x;
```

getting the href value and then targeting it .. solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try href="javascript:alert ('test')" or onclick="alert ('test')"

Comment: ` href="javascript:alert ('test')"` i tried this but, this dosen;t worked. I need to trigger using js only .

Comment: @KamranKhatti jquery js same bro .. i need to trigger the function present inside href using javascript/jquery code

Comment: i don;t know what the function defination is ..  `<a href="javascript:hello()">test</a>` anyway i can just call `hello()` from js code.. like `$("#id").click()` but, it isn't working

Comment: @KamranKhatti thanks for your time .. finally figured it out... `var x = $('#myLink').attr("href")
window.location = x;` this is working.